# Matlab: Making code for coinflip

Tags: matlab

I'm having trouble with this problem since I'm new to matlab

"Use help to learn about the built in function ‘rand’.  Write a script to use the rand function to generate a sequence of ‘head’ or ‘tail’ where one is head and zero is tail.  The other function that you need to use is ‘round’ to convert the output of the ‘rand’ function to an integer.  When we run your function it should display something like this: “T H T T H H H…..”.

I've used the help function and searched online but I still don't understand the random function.

I've used

> > flip = random('norm',1:10,1)

flip =

```
1.0774    0.7859    1.8865    3.9932    6.5326    5.2303    7.3714    7.7744   10.1174    8.9109
```

As you can see, it keeps giving me random numbers.  I want my numbers to be either 0 or 1.
I know the 10 in 1:10 will display 10 values, but what does the two 1's mean?

I'd appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as follow:

```
faceId=rand(1,10)<0.5
  faceId =
      1     1     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0

faceName='TH';

faceName(faceId+1)
  ans =
  THHHHTTHTH
```

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, there's also the `randi` function (at least from 2011b onwards):

```
faceId = randi(2,1,10) % generates random integers between 1 and 2 (inclusively)
faceId =

     2     2     2     1     1     2     2     1     1     2
```

That avoids the need for the `< 0.5` comparison and the `+1`